# Como ejecutar codigo python desde asp.net core en razor pages

Tags: python, .net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

Amigos, estoy desarrollando una web, la cual necesito integrar una pequeña parte que desarrolle en python, pero no se como ejecutarla y pasar parametros desde asp.net core en razor pages.

Vi este ejemplo pero no se si pueda funcionar en .net core
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJXOe60sciA&ab_channel=hdeleon.net

Agradeszco mucha su ayuda

Comment: Qué tienes pensado retornar cuando ejecutes el archivo de Python?
O sea, necesitas que solo se muestre cosas en la consola?

Da mas detalles de lo que necesitas hacer.

He manejado ejecución de archivos de python de otra manera a la del video pero efectiva, pero necesito que des mas detalles para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Buenas noches, quiero poder ponerlo a generar unos pdf, en segundo plano para no sobre cargar mi web en .net core. pero tambien podria mas adelante necesitar leer algun valor de respuesta de este script de python

Answer (score 0):

Te explico como lo he trabajado.

1. Los scripts de Python los puedes convertir en ejecutables `.exe` y así aprovechas para el tema de seguridad del sitio. Con este video puedes ayudarte para ello: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vr9vl0qlggE&list=PLePBGIflFGil6M_kGLaJmVbyPxeH8zHwS&index=1&t=364s
2. Ahora que ya tienes el script de Python en el cual especificas lo que necesites, el reto es llevarlo a `.Net Core` para ejecutarlo. Y lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"file.exe")
{
    Verb = "runas",
    UseShellExecute = true,
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

**Qué hacemos?**

Especificamos un objeto de tipo `Process` y lo configuramos con el nombre del archivo o la ruta donde lo tengas listo. Los atributos de esta configuración son los siguientes:

Verb = "runas": Especifica que el archivo se ejecutara en modo administrador.

UseShellExecute = true: Usa el Shell de Windows para la ejecución.

WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden: Especificamos que la ejecución del Shell de Windows no será visible.

**Cómo se envían parámetros?**

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@$"C:\Program Files (x86)\{prmFileName}")
{
    ArgumentList = { $"{prmPrimero}", $"{prmSegundo}" },
    Verb = "runas",
    UseShellExecute = true,
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Agregamos un nuevo atributo a nuestro objeto `Process`:

ArgumentList = { $"{prmPrimero}", $"{prmSegundo}" }: Donde especificamos los argumentos que desea recibir el script de Python.

**Ahora como alistar el script para que reciba estos parámetros:**

```
import argparse
import os
import time


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('parametro1')
parser.add_argument('parametro2')

args = parser.parse_args()
variables = vars(args)
Parameter1 = int(variables.get('parametro1'))
Parameter2 = int(variables.get('parametro2'))

print("Id Well: ", Parameter1, type(Parameter1))
print("Interval: ", Parameter2, type(Parameter2))

time.sleep(5)
os.system("pause")
```

Se hace uso de la librería `argparse` para poder recibir parámetros.
Los cuales al final te permite leer los datos y guardarlos en forma de diccionario.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta es de gran ayuda para mi, mañana lo pondré en práctica y te comento como me va

Comment: Amigo, espero todo este en orden, mi hmno estoy probando el codigo y se esta ejecutando pero no estoy obteniendo lo que necesito, es decir si se ejecuta, incluso cambie la propiedad  WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden a normal para ver si se ejecuta la ventana de comandos, y si se alcanza a ver la ventana pero cuando voy a la carpeta para ver si creo o no el archivo que estoy esperando resulta que no esta ahi, (Cuando lo ejecuto manualmente si lo crea), no se si depronto sea algun tema de tiempo de ejecucion, pero tampoco se como cambiarlo.